# How to make a dropdown option in top navigation menu for blogger

Tags: drop-down-menu, menu, blogger

I am looking to make a drop down for some of the option in the main navigation  menu, but nothing I try seems to work. Current HTML without drop down:

```
<center>
   <li style="font-weight: normal;"><a href="http://www.latoyah.co.uk/"><b>Home</b></a></li>
   <br />
   <li style="font-weight: normal;"><a href="http://www.latoyah.co.uk/p/about-me.html"><b>About</b></a></li>
   <br />
   <li><a href="http://www.latoyah.co.uk/p/contact-me.html"><b>Contact</b></a><br /></li>
   <li style="font-weight: normal;"><a href="http://www.latoyah.co.uk/p/slimming-world-recipes.html"><b>Slimming Recipes</b></a></li>
   <br />
   <li style="font-weight: normal;"><a href="https://www.latoyah.co.uk/p/slimming-meal-plans.html"><b>Meal Plans</b></a></li>
   <li style="font-weight: normal;"><a href="http://www.latoyah.co.uk/p/lifestyle.html"><b>Lifestyle &amp; Reviews</b></a></li>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a dropdown menu in HTML, follow this form

Navigation Menu

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Navigation Menu with Dropdown Menu

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Dropdown Menu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a dropdown you need to add css and edit your code.

You can Check here - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp